# MT5 on python not working properly and gives error message AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ask'

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium, metatrader5

So i have a piece of code which essentially is this

```
price_three = mt5.symbol_info_tick(thr_currency_text).ask
a
```

and gives the error message

```
price_three = mt5.symbol_info_tick(thr_currency_text).ask
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ask'
```

however, i am using the code earlier on and is still not working.

```
price_two = mt5.symbol_info_tick(sec_currency_text).ask
price = mt5.symbol_info_tick(temp_currency_text).ask
```

I have uninstalled the mt5 and installed it back on the command prompt and still not working. didn't know how to get around this solution. Also when it mentions temp/sec/thr_currency_text it has no correlation to anything but a couple of variables. and still won't work

Comment: mt5.symbol_info_tick(thr_currency_text) - This thing is returning None so you check your code again to see why it is returning None.  Please add the complete code so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you did not declare or specify
`thr_currency_text`